# Translation issue - wrong language is displayed by default

Tags: c#, localization, multilingual, cultureinfo

I have just started writing a multilingual application for the very first time. I have read about the concept of language resource files and I think I get the main idea. I have tried to implement it, and instantly found an issue:

I have entered the default language strings to a resx file, and then added another resource file (for example: UIStrings.en.resx). Since my company is not based in England / other English speaking countries, our applications are primarily written in our language. Thus default language is our language (Slovenian).

When I add the .en.resx file and insert the correct translations and run the program it now displays *English* text. I figured that is because

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = "en-US"
```

while

```
CultureInfo.Currentculture = "sl-SI"
```

I figure this is because I am running English version of windows (though all the properties in *Regional Options* are set correctly to Slovenian settings).

How can I make the application display the strings in the users language, not the installed windows language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out this blog post that answers my question.

If anyone else is struggling with this, here is what you do:

> So, if you are using the most common
>   version of Windows (Englis version),
>   you are stuck with the “en-US”
>   culture; hence, your application will
>   always use your English resource. In
>   order to mitigate this, you can
>   perform a little trick at your
>   application startup. You can mislead
>   your application to look in your
>   CurrentCulture property instead of
>   CurrentUICulture property. At the
>   application startup, you can write
>   something like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

> This way, your application will use
>   your globalization setting instead of
>   your default windows localization
>   setting. Your application will be
>   localized to your globalization
>   language and culture. If you change
>   the Regional Settings in your Control
>   Panel, your application language and
>   culture will change automatically.

Comment: That's exactly what I told you and what I've earned is a -1 :)

Comment: @Thomas: No, you told me to hard code it to a language (culture info) of my preference. I do not want it fixed, nor do I want to manually store it anywhere. I wanted the application to use culture set in the Windows Regional Options.

Comment: Sorry, but your question was *How can I make the application display the strings in the users language, not the installed windows language?*, so I thought you don't want to use any windows options. But whatever works for you man, I don't care..

Comment: @Thomas: Don't get me wrong I still appreciate your answer, I just don't think it helped me.